# What does this condition mean for Cauchy's integral formula?

Tags: complex-analysis

> ** **Theorem:** **
>
> Suppose that $\Omega$ is a simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$,
>   that $f \in H(\Omega)$, that $\Gamma$ is a simple closed contour in
>   $\Omega$ and that $w \in \text{Int} (\Gamma$) then:
>
> $$f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}~dz$$

I don't understand what "$w \in \text{Int} (\Gamma$)" means. In my notes i can't seem to find a definition for $\text{Int} (\Gamma$).

Could anyone clear this up?

Comment: Think I got it that means $w$ is an interior point of $\Gamma$ correct? So essentially $w$ is inside the area defined by the contour $\Gamma$

Comment: it should be ${\rm int}( \Omega)$, the interior of the domain $\Omega$.

Comment: @Varde You figured it out correctly.

Comment: @janmarqz No, I think it should be $\text{Int}(\Gamma)$.

Comment: @janmarqz You sure? I my book it says $\Gamma$ but since $\Gamma$ is in $\Omega$ then so if $w \in \Gamma \implies w \in \Omega$.

Comment: @EclipseSun, No way, closed curves have not interior :P

Comment: @janmarqz I think they do. Consider a circle of arbitrary radius for example. Then it is the inside of the circle defined by the circumference I think.

Comment: @janmarqz The interior of a closed curve is not the same as the interior of the closed curve as a set. It means the bounded region enclosed by the curve.

Comment: @Varde: curves are to skinny to support open disks of the plane :P

Comment: @EclipseSun: to avoid confusions instead one should use: **the bounded region of the contour** :P

Comment: @janmarqz Maybe you are right. But the term **interior** is more popular.

Comment: @janmarqz It's a collision of terminology. The complement of a Jordan curve in the plane consists of two connected components. One of the two is bounded, the other unbounded. The bounded component is called the interior of the curve, and the unbounded one is called the exterior. Unfortunately, the same words are used for topological concepts.

Comment: **interior** is a *technical term*  so it can no be ambiguous

Comment: @janmarqz "interior" is several technical terms. It can be ambiguous which one is used.

Comment: @DanielFischer: you are giving me the validity needed to rest my case

Comment: we are talking about the complex plane topology

Comment: @janmarqz No. In that place, it refers to the components of the complement of the Jordan curve $\Gamma$.

Comment: and this is not topology in the complex plane?

Comment: please  take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula#Theorem

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega \in {\rm Int}(\Gamma)$ means that $\Omega$ is in the interior of $\Gamma$. 
*Hope I helped!*

Answer (score 0):

This picture illustrates the situation:
[image]

The interior of $\Omega$ is all with gray colors, $\Gamma$ (in blue) is the contour in the interior of $\Omega$ and $w$ is in the bounded part of $\Gamma$ (a.k.a the "interior" of $\Gamma$ as the others would like to call).